# How do you bind a key sequence to shell command?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, keybindings

Using stock Terminal.app on El Capitan, the effort is to set up a shortcut in a sense, that upon press it would execute a specific command.

Consulting `man` pages for `bind` command following steps have been taken but yielded no results.

**First approach** was to place the setting inside `~/.inputrc` file and let the login session do its work. The current state of the file is:

```
"\C-s": "ssh hostname"
```

**Second**, used `bind` command directly.

```
$ bind '"\C-s": "ssh hostname"'
```

appendix:

GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a newline character to the end, for example:

```
bind '"\C-s": "ssh hostname\n"'
```

Another thing is what key sequence you want to bind the command to, and if it's not already handled by the system. For example, for <kbd>F12</kbd>, which is available, you'd use:

```
bind '"\e[24~": "ssh hostname\n"'
```

Comment: The second suggestion worked as advertised. However, I was not able to replicate it with the first one, not even using different set of letters. Anyway, I thank You.

Comment: Isn't `-x` supposed to be used for shell command bindings? From `help bind` in bash: `-x  keyseq:shell-command Cause SHELL-COMMAND to be executed when KEYSEQ is entered.`